# How to keep an image sharp when Downsizing and Saving for Web & Devices in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am saving my image for a website and downsizing it by 100 px. When I decrease the size just a bit it looses its sharpness. How can I maintain that?[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [My web logo looks pixelated after resizing](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15808/my-web-logo-looks-pixelated-after-resizing)

Comment: That question pertains to working in Photoshop, this one is asking about Illustrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. At least, you can't with that logo. At the large size, you will note that a lot of your line work is barely 1px in width and that the nice hand-drawn feel is based on a line quality that varies barely by a pixel here or there.

An you can't scale a 1px line below 1px and expect it to keep any fidelity.

What I'd suggest is creating a separate version of the logo to handle the resolution at that small size. Remove the elements that simply can't be rendered on screen at that size--namely the 1px outline shadow. Or, one suggestion...at that size, remove the underline from the word, and place the bug to the left or right of the type at the same size. It's OK to have variations of your logo for different applications.

Answer (score 0):

Resize first, then save for web. And in the Save for Web window be certain you are setting the Anti-Alias method to either "type optimized" or "art optimized" accordingly.